# ImageCaptureCore error -9933 when ICScannerFunctionalUnit set to scan in black & white

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, image-capture, scanning

I'm making an application to easily scan to multiple page pdf files. The project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/levidhuyvetter/Scanner), just in case you want to have a look at all of the project code.

I'm having an issue with scanning in black & white.

This is the method that gets called when I press the button to start scanning.

```
- (IBAction)scan:(id)sender {
    //Get the selected scanner and it's functional unit
    ICScannerDevice *scanner = [self selectedScanner];
    ICScannerFunctionalUnit *unit = [scanner selectedFunctionalUnit];

    //If there is no scan or overviewscan in progress
    if (![unit overviewScanInProgress] && ![unit scanInProgress]) {
        //Setup the functional unit and start the scan
        [unit setScanArea:[self scanArea]];
        [unit setResolution:[[unit supportedResolutions] indexGreaterThanOrEqualToIndex:[[resolutionPopUpButton selectedItem] tag]]];
        [unit setBitDepth:ICScannerBitDepth8Bits];
        [unit setMeasurementUnit:ICScannerMeasurementUnitCentimeters];
        [unit setThresholdForBlackAndWhiteScanning:0];
        [unit setUsesThresholdForBlackAndWhiteScanning:YES];
        [unit setPixelDataType:[kindSegmentedControl selectedSegment]];
        [scanner requestScan];
    } else {
        //Cancel the ongoing scan
        [scanner cancelScan];
    }
}
```

I'm setting the `pixelDataType` to an integer that I get from an `NSSegmentedControl`. When the first segment is selected this will return 0, which is the same as `ICScannerPixelDataTypeBW`.

However, despite everything working fine when the second and the third segment are selected (which are `ICScannerPixelDataTypeGray` and `ICScannerPixelDataTypeRGB`), the scanner does nothing when set to scan black & white.

There is very little documentation available on the scanning part of `ImageCaptureCore`, but I found those properties describing a threshold for black & white scanning on [this website](http://uri-labs.com/macosx_headers/ICScannerFunctionalUnits_h/Classes/ICScannerFunctionalUnit/index.html), but none of them worked for me.

I know this is a part of the ImageCaptureCore API that doesn't get used by many people very often, but I really hope someone knows, or at least can find out, a solution to my problem.

**Edit:**

I added `- (void)device:(ICDevice *)device didEncounterError:(NSError *)error` to my implementation and logged the error, which is:

```
2014-02-01 21:55:16.260 Scanner[4131:903] Error Domain=com.apple.ImageCaptureCore Code=-9933 UserInfo=0x1005763f0 "An error occurred during scanning."
```

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to perform headless scanning using ImageCaptureCore framework akin to what you are describing here. The problem I am facing is that I am not getting any callbacks after the `requestScan` call. I have asked a question on SO regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434605/imagecapturecore-functionality-not-getting-callbacks-despite-the-delegates-bein , but to no avail. Could you please see what I may be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little hint (intentional or not) from the other answer, I figured things out by myself.

What you have to do is to set `bitDepth` to `ICScannerBitDepth1Bit`, as what you're trying to scan is a 1 bit per pixel image.

This in turn disables scanning in grayscale or rgb.

Since I can't award bounties to my own questions, I will award the bounty to the question I got the hint from.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the ImageCaptureCore error codes in ICCommonConstants.h.

The error you mention is

```
ICReturnReceivedUnsolicitedScannerErrorInfo   = -9933
```

Maybe your scanner simply does not support scanning in Black & White? Since Grayscale works, do you even want to use BW?

From the headers:

```
/*!
  @enum ICScannerPixelDataType
  @abstract Pixel data types. Corresponds to "ICAP_PIXELTYPE" of the TWAIN Specification.
  @constant ICScannerPixelDataTypeBW Monochrome 1 bit pixel image.
  @constant ICScannerPixelDataTypeGray 8 bit pixel Gray color space.
  @constant ICScannerPixelDataTypeRGB Color image RGB color space.
  @constant ICScannerPixelDataTypePalette Indexed Color image.
  @constant ICScannerPixelDataTypeCMY Color image in CMY color space.
  @constant ICScannerPixelDataTypeCMYK Color image in CMYK color space.
  @constant ICScannerPixelDataTypeYUV Color image in YUV color space.
  @constant ICScannerPixelDataTypeYUVK Color image in YUVK color space.
  @constant ICScannerPixelDataTypeCIEXYZ Color image in CIEXYZ color space.
*/

enum
{
    ICScannerPixelDataTypeBW      = 0,
    ICScannerPixelDataTypeGray    = 1,
    ICScannerPixelDataTypeRGB     = 2,
    ICScannerPixelDataTypePalette = 3,
    ICScannerPixelDataTypeCMY     = 4,
    ICScannerPixelDataTypeCMYK    = 5,
    ICScannerPixelDataTypeYUV     = 6,
    ICScannerPixelDataTypeYUVK    = 7,
    ICScannerPixelDataTypeCIEXYZ  = 8
};
typedef NSUInteger ICScannerPixelDataType;
```

Do you really want to support a 1bit per pixel image?

Comment: Yeah I do want to support black & white. The application is designed for scanning text documents. I personally like to scan text documents in black & white to keep the file size low, and the quality isn't really important in that case. Is there a way I could achieve the same result by converting the grayscale image? CoreImage perhaps? What would be the best way to do it with CoreImage?